# Python reading files in different local drive locations

Tags: python

Could someone shed me some lights on the file path matter in Python?

For example my codes need to read a batch of files, the file names are listed and stored in a .txt file, C:\filelist.txt, which content is:

```
C:\1stfile.txt
C:\2ndfile.txt
C:\3rdfile.txt
C:\4thfile.txt
C:\5thfile.txt
```

And the codes start with:

```
list_open = open('c:\\aaa.txt')
read_list = list_open.read()
line_in_list = read_list.split('\n')
```

all run fine. But if I want to read files in another path, such as:

```
C:\WorkingFolder\6thfile.txt
C:\WorkingFolder\7thfile.txt
C:\WorkingFolder\8thfile.txt
C:\WorkingFolder\9thfile.txt
C:\WorkingFolder\10thfile.txt
```

It doesn’t work. I guess the path here C:\WorkingFolder\ is not properly put so Python cannot recognize it.

So in what way I shall put it? Thanks.

---

---

---

hello all,

sorry that maybe i didn't make my self clear.

the problem is, a text file, c:\aaa.txt contains below:

```
C:\1stfile.txt
C:\WorkingFolder\1stfile.txt
```

why only C:\1stfile.txt is readable, but the other one not?

Comment: Are all the strings properly escaped, i.e. `"C:\\WorkingFolder\\10thfile.txt"`, or `r"C:\WorkingFolder\10thfile.txt"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your program isn't working is that you're not changing the directory properly. Use [os.chdir()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chdir) to do so, then open the files as normal:

```
import os

path = "C:\\WorkingFolder\\"

# Check current working directory.
retval = os.getcwd()

print "Current working directory %s" % retval

# Now change the directory
os.chdir( path )

# Check current working directory.
retval = os.getcwd()

print "Directory changed successfully %s" % retval
```

REFERENCES:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_chdir.htm

Answer (score 2):

```
import os

BASEDIR = "c:\\WorkingFolder"

list_open = open(os.path.join(BASEDIR, 'aaa.txt'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply try using forward slashes instead.

```
list_open = open("C:/WorkingFolder/6thfile.txt", "rt")
```

It works for me.